# Testing Sinatra app for get with request.body

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-1.8.7

Suppose I have an endpoint like so:

```
get "/foo" do
    request.body.rewind
    data = request.body.read
    # some logic goes here
end
```

How do I test this in Sinatra?

If I try:

```
it "gets /foo" do
    payload = {:bar => "baz"}
    get "/foo", payload
end
```

the payload gets sent as get parameters and not as request.body.

I am not able to change the endpoint to accept params instead of request.body at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test/blob/4b6d2cfc684200bc869acfd39936f3927a9f77cb/lib/rack/test.rb#L215), you can specify it in `env` with key `:input`, like so:

```
get "/foo", {}, {:input => JSON.generate(payload)}
```

assuming that the input is in json.